# Nested image in bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

Alright so I am trying to make a gallery with bootstrap but no matter what I keep on failing with this.

Look at the image bellow to see the grid itself how it should look

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="d-flex gallery justify-content-center flex-wrap">
    <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <img class="col-3" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/39/C_Hello_World_Program.png/402px-C_Hello_World_Program.png" />
        <img class="col-3" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/39/C_Hello_World_Program.png/402px-C_Hello_World_Program.png" />
        <img class="col-3" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/39/C_Hello_World_Program.png/402px-C_Hello_World_Program.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-9 d-flex row">
        <div class="col-9 d-flex flex-wrap">
            <img class="col-12" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/39/C_Hello_World_Program.png/402px-C_Hello_World_Program.png" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-3">
            <img class="col-12" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/39/C_Hello_World_Program.png/402px-C_Hello_World_Program.png" />
            <img class="col-12" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/39/C_Hello_World_Program.png/402px-C_Hello_World_Program.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Test 
https://codepen.io/Tomitza93/pen/XWrRKwq

And this is how it should actually look
https://prnt.sc/oy33tc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify this section

```
 <div class="col-9 d-flex row">
    <div class="col-8 d-flex flex-wrap">
        <img class="col-12" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/39/C_Hello_World_Program.png/402px-C_Hello_World_Program.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
        <img class="col-12" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/39/C_Hello_World_Program.png/402px-C_Hello_World_Program.png" />
        <img class="col-12" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/39/C_Hello_World_Program.png/402px-C_Hello_World_Program.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and add this css

```
.gallery .col-12 , .gallery .col-3, .gallery .col-9, .gallery .col-8 , .gallery .col-4{
   padding: 2px !important
}
```

Comment: That just adds padding to it, I want it to be sorted, like the big image in the second row should be as wide as the two ones above

Comment: Yeah this one is way better! Thanks!